# Parse Information and only return matched information

Tags: powershell

I need help only returning the output of positive 5 or greater from the result

```
$string = "positives"
$fileread = "C:\Users\test\desktop\testttt.txt"
Select-String $string $fileread -Context 0, 2 | % { $_.line + $_.Context.PostContext } | format-table
```

file testttt.txt: some content inside

```
  "date": "2019-05-13 17:14:10",
      "positives": 4,
      "total": 72,
      "sha256":"7b4aceaadd78ec496c6fd9a284d7411c5085f4efd156e7fe2bac0df872a01034"
```

this is the result when I ran the command:

```
 "positives": 4,      "total": 63,       "sha256": "6f9c383bdf061c9ed7415c89474f1d04b9acec6af3cc87dd3aa394db9c6a7867"
  "positives": 4,      "total": 72,       "sha256": "7b4aceaadd78ec496c6fd9a284d7411c5085f4efd156e7fe2bac0df872a01034"
  "positives": 4,      "total": 71,       "sha256": "75503c537e8dc0b30c0fbc78a9b1dfc966ca7c97caa0142c38201ab7de1c0631"
  "positives": 4,      "total": 73,       "sha256": "5a9f454578cf84e196346ed79b16f4614271c6748846b3f192cba2e39084ce55"
  "positives": 4,      "total": 73,       "sha256": "de888d1402cc7347c22e53b660641789f5bb4ac73d6dc0eb054e3d813425c305"
  "positives": 4,      "total": 71,       "sha256": "82e55e6abdd9d2a78db2cae8bbd048fcb0249651820aebbd7fcaadc6d5252bff"
  "positives": 5,      "total": 71,       "sha256": "6d371555e08ba2b2397fd44a0db31605e7def831585c4c11dbb21c70d89e3b35"
  "positives": 6,      "total": 68,       "sha256": "51350e36d2cef84097077a4f5f12e5ee359625ec0f776403895039c4442860fa"
  "positives": 17,      "total": 69,       "sha256": "9968827ab119c8e8362c8a5cbef4389c2c36a08eda30ce091fe9a8e19f9eec0d"
  "positives": 18,      "total": 70,       "sha256": "f57241e8c01595bc6f2abfdb0df3a8e4bbb5746009ff6063ab185587211cacef"
  "positives": 55,      "total": 71,       "sha256": "0c802ce9e48b3c2e22b34f97090056de44ee1fca7da4f88c48f7b79f6280c187"
  "positives": 35,      "total": 70,       "sha256": "9e06288e6ccdcf2d8394d297de6b1f9df6810c797e25fe20e42da64a4f8f1c2e"
  "positives": 46,      "total": 71,       "sha256": "8454d6cb1603949423b9593bebc820a937bd90690094c6fabff25b11ca6ec98d"
  "positives": 12,      "total": 70,       "sha256": "67bd4c84c0940a9f22baaadd35acd04a167ceb0280051666eaf4f8cef271a8b6"
  "positives": 60,      "total": 70,       "sha256": "e374346869470dd4c26de8380c26cc6833e875456216aa624493f475e0c8e7e6"
  "positives": 14,      "total": 70,       "sha256": "c5bd171025b10ba777008c349b26863a5259a7f45ad46ab71d9f227a2959ab83"
  "positives": 61,      "total": 71,       "sha256": "7f7d3ede921b7dca9c12d97c5d770fe0c58a913d91fcfef942874ef9e535c38d"
  "positives": 10,      "total": 70,       "sha256": "75e055f55d7130fbcee12c8d89a7a400eed7f59f131bb9d1a5f6909b7a776dc1"
  "positives": 51,      "total": 57,       "sha256": "43b6eb575e89f4f4637c3cb979a1c9cd0af69a6aa13c98a9a44820e937f0d056"
  "positives": 5,      "total": 56,       "sha256": "b351fd6c98acc5648184e9bb01152975c0fc98c1816d1441d042d9b76b9e207c"
  "positives": 7,      "total": 57,       "sha256": "1802dd8641fa40ffeccd79888726a1fea579d8f9fd7fb1d23e0b1e91ddcd2867"
  "positives": 53,      "total": 56,       "sha256": "bd75e387fca7ca6f3a2ad3403f2cd4adc55fa4fde69e5d8785edbe6c47e0aab1"
  "positives": 57,      "total": 62,       "sha256": "494358b446fb61afcd7c9c871edb5cbfcbba33859a9bd7f47a553476bea3810b"
  "positives": 6,      "total": 66,       "sha256": "891ba3880fa58a899ccf13e8f11104c7207c20f85a17d098bbef57824f6e4907"
  "positives": 61,      "total": 67,       "sha256": "4b40543ac6cca09c48259171ea036b44ac51fb5aecfd7f27891b22d2d2c8cfe3"
  "positives": 56,      "total": 68,       "sha256": "136e5b54c9751bf0cd2b07f73680ee5c152fe9de82c5a14764c0137e1793167a"
  "positives": 31,      "total": 68,       "sha256": "8a84ab39bebb6a05ec3e430f76d43356b9778c9f80a3583efa7efd21a250748c"
  "positives": 28,      "total": 61,       "sha256": "34240815dd9521a822cc3f2c3ceecbe1ad5ea81a725b8cce4e23978b118c6c2c"
  "positives": 17,      "total": 66,       "sha256": "72baea57054415c69dbef9a303183e28946c33faeb354c3e849622dbf0d6da81"
```

Comment: please add a few lines of the input file, the output you are getting from  that file, and the output you _want_ from the input ... and how to decide what is wanted.

Comment: This looks like a snippet out of a structured format file. You're IMO much better of using `ConvertFrom-Json` on the file content and dealing with the object directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This will do the needful:**

```
$string = "positives`": *([5-9]|\d\d+)"
$fileread = "Y:\testttt.txt"
Select-String -Path $fileread -Pattern $string -Context 0,2 | % { $_.line + $_.Context.PostContext }
```

**Example Results:**

```
  "positives": 5,      "total": 71,       "sha256": "6d371555e08ba2b2397fd44a0db31605e7def831585c4c11dbb21c70d89e3b35"
  "positives": 14,      "total": 70,       "sha256": "c5bd171025b10ba777008c349b26863a5259a7f45ad46ab71d9f227a2959ab83"
  "positives": 1964,      "total": 70,       "sha256": "c5bd171025b10ba777008c349b26863a5259a7f45ad46ab71d9f227a2959ab83"
```

**Test File used:**

```
  "date": "2019-05-13 17:14:10",
      "positives": 4,
      "total": 72,
      "sha256":"7b4aceaadd78ec496c6fd9a284d7411c5085f4efd156e7fe2bac0df872a01034"
  "date": "2019-05-13 17:14:10",
      "positives": 5,
      "total": 71,
      "sha256": "6d371555e08ba2b2397fd44a0db31605e7def831585c4c11dbb21c70d89e3b35"
  "date": "2019-05-13 17:14:10",
      "positives": 4,
      "total": 72,
      "sha256":"7b4aceaadd78ec496c6fd9a284d7411c5085f4efd156e7fe2bac0df872a01034"
  "date": "2019-05-13 17:14:10",
      "positives": 14,
      "total": 70,
      "sha256": "c5bd171025b10ba777008c349b26863a5259a7f45ad46ab71d9f227a2959ab83"
  "date": "2019-05-13 17:14:10",
      "positives": 1964,
      "total": 70,
      "sha256": "c5bd171025b10ba777008c349b26863a5259a7f45ad46ab71d9f227a2959ab83"
```

Due to newer answers sorting first, it looks like they're more likely to be seen 1st and be thought of as being first that's a bit.. odd.

Well, in any case, I had two more Versions of this I wanted to post last night but literally had to run to catch the train instead.

Both of these improve the script by removing the use of a For Loop, to produce results faster, both in the exact original format, and also as a table output.=

**This will generate the results as originally outlined faster than using a For Loop:**

```
$string = "positives`": *([5-9]|\d\d+)"
$fileread = "Y:\testttt.txt"
(Select-String $string $fileread -Context 0, 2 | select  @{n="Results";e={$_.line + $_.Context.PostContext} } ).Results
```

**Example Results:**

```
PS Y:\> (Select-String $string $fileread -Context 0, 2 | select  @{n="Results";e={$_.line + $_.Context.PostContext} } ).Results
      "positives": 5,      "total": 71,       "sha256": "6d371555e08ba2b2397fd44a0db31605e7def831585c4c11dbb21c70d89e3b35"
      "positives": 14,      "total": 70,       "sha256": "c5bd171025b10ba777008c349b26863a5259a7f45ad46ab71d9f227a2959ab83
      "positives": 1964,      "total": 70,       "sha256": "c5bd171025b10ba777008c349b26863a5259a7f45ad46ab71d9f227a2959ab83"
```

**This Parses the info into a table with columns of the pertinent Information without a For-loop which will make it faster.**

```
$string = "positives`": *([5-9]|\d\d+)"
$fileread = "Y:\testttt.txt"
Select-String $string $fileread -Context 0, 2 |  select (
    @{n="Positives";e={$($("$($_.line)" -split ':')[1]).trim() -replace '[\t ,]*','' } },
    @{n="Total";e={$($($($_.Context.PostContext) -split ':')[1]).trim() -replace ',.*','' } },
    @{n="Cipher";e={$($($($($_.Context.PostContext) -split ':') -split ',')[3]).trim() -replace '[\t "]+','' } },
    @{n="Hash";e={$($($($_.Context.PostContext) -split ':')[3]).trim() -replace '[\t "]+','' } }
) | FT
```

**And the results of that look like this:**

```
Positives Total Cipher Hash                                                            
--------- ----- ------ ----                                                            
5         71    sha256 6d371555e08ba2b2397fd44a0db31605e7def831585c4c11dbb21c70d89e3b35
14        70    sha256 c5bd171025b10ba777008c349b26863a5259a7f45ad46ab71d9f227a2959ab83
1964      70    sha256 c5bd171025b10ba777008c349b26863a5259a7f45ad46ab71d9f227a2959ab83
```

Comment: Glad to help, I didn;t post it, but I also had a faster method (use select instead of For) and I did one that put it all in a  table as you might prefer that, also using Select instead of For, I am going to get on my desktop and post them up in a bit at the end. of the above solution so you can see those other Options:

Comment: This has helped me a lot. Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your file is something like below:

```
"date": "2019-05-13 17:14:10",
"positives": 3,
"total": 73,
"sha256":"3b4aceaadd78ec496c6fd9a284d7411c5085f4efd156e7fe2bac0df872a01034"
"date": "2019-05-13 17:14:10",
"positives": 4,
"total": 74,
"sha256":"4b4aceaadd78ec496c6fd9a284d7411c5085f4efd156e7fe2bac0df872a01034"
"date": "2019-05-13 17:14:10",
"positives": 5,
"total": 75,
"sha256":"5b4aceaadd78ec496c6fd9a284d7411c5085f4efd156e7fe2bac0df872a01034"
"date": "2019-05-13 17:14:10",
"positives": 6,
"total": 76,
"sha256":"6b4aceaadd78ec496c6fd9a284d7411c5085f4efd156e7fe2bac0df872a01034"
```

Then you can get only items with 'positives: X' with X greater than or equal to 5 like this:

```
$pattern = "`"positives`": (\d+)"
$targetFile = ".\testttt.txt"

Select-String -Path $targetFile -Pattern $pattern -Context 0,2 |
    Where-Object { $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value -ge 5 } |
        ForEach-Object {
            $total = $($_.Context.PostContext[0] -match ": (\d+)" | Out-Null; $Matches)
            $hash = $($_.Context.PostContext[1] -match "`"(\w+)`":`"([a-z0-9]+)`"" | Out-Null; $Matches)

            [PsCustomObject]@{
                Positives = $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value
                Total     = $total[1]
                Algorithm = $hash[1]
                HashValue = $hash[2]
            }
        }
```

A little bit clunky, but it does give you a nice collection of objects for easier manipulation, or display:

```
Positives Total Algorithm HashValue                                                       
--------- ----- --------- ---------                                                       
5         75    sha256    5b4aceaadd78ec496c6fd9a284d7411c5085f4efd156e7fe2bac0df872a01034
6         76    sha256    6b4aceaadd78ec496c6fd9a284d7411c5085f4efd156e7fe2bac0df872a01034
```